# chemical laboratory equipment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I want to include some drawings with Erlenmeyer flask, Bunsen burner and 
so on in LaTeX.

I browsed the http://texample.net gallery. I found some examples for chemical structures, molecules and so. But I did not find any example for lab equipment.

- Does TikZ provide a library that helps to construct this?
- Are there any other TikZ sites where I can find examples?
- Does anybody had a similar task and found a solution to share?

I am not fixed on TikZ. Are there other means to make this drawings?

I looked at `pst-labo`. How difficult would it be to extend the options it provides?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "support"?  Do you mean, "Is there a tikz library for this?", do you mean "Are there some examples I can cut-and-paste?", or what?  Have you looked at texample.net, are there any examples there?

Comment: you do not like pstricks?

Comment: I guess the OP would like a pre-built library where he can simply choose particular bits of kit.

Comment: Indeed, I can use TikZ as I would do with pencil and circle. But I don't want to use each line individually but use a template that leads my pencil. So, yes a TikZ-library would be very interesting. Examples of lab things are also great.

Comment: What's wrong with `pst-labo`? You're saying you're not fixed on TikZ...

Comment: But can you use pst-labo in pdflatex?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate with some very good answers. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/a-way-to-draw-a-lab-apparatus/55944#55944

Answer (score 4):

Run it with `xelatex` or with package `auto-pst-pdf` also with `pdflatex --shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pstDistillation

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly for what you're looking, but it sounds like there are no pre-built packages that do exactly what you need.  My suggestion would be to find some high quality vector images for the lab equipment ([openclipart.org](http://www.openclipart.org/) has some excellent examples) and then use that as clip art inside a Ti*k*Z picture, which you could also integrate into the aforementioned [Ti*k*Z examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/chemistry/).  One approach to do that is to convert the SVG images from openclipart.org directly into Ti*k*Z code.  The easiest way to do this of which I know is to load the images into [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and then use [this patch](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/).  An alternative approach is to convert the SVG images to PDFs (which can also be done in Inkscape) and then inserting them into your Ti*k*Z picture as nodes.  For example:

```
\node (flask) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{flask.pdf}};
```