# TikZ: How to make a convex lens

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make a convex lens with `TikZ`?

I tried using arcs but this doesn't look right.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xr}{0.35}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yr}{2}

  \draw (0, 0) coordinate (O) arc[x radius = \xr cm, y radius = \yr cm,
  start angle = 90, end angle = 270];
  \draw (O) arc[x radius = \xr cm, y radius = \yr cm,
  start angle = 90, end angle = -90];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like the arcs to meet at a sharp corner not rounded.

[image]

Comment: Slightly related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33460/tikz-library-for-optics (Edit: It doesn't exactly answer your question, I just added it for reference.)

Comment: Depending on where you're heading, you might want to have a look at [pst-optexp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-optexp).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one suggestion:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lensRadius}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lensHeight}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\startAngle}{asin(\lensHeight/\lensRadius)}

  \draw (0,\lensHeight) arc[start angle=180-\startAngle,delta angle=2*\startAngle,radius=\lensRadius];
  \draw (0,\lensHeight) arc[start angle=\startAngle,delta angle=-2*\startAngle,radius=\lensRadius];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Slightly modified, for filling, and better line ends:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lensRadius}{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lensHeight}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\startAngle}{asin(\lensHeight/\lensRadius)}

  \draw [fill=blue!15]  (0,\lensHeight)
  arc[start angle=180-\startAngle,delta angle=2*\startAngle,radius=\lensRadius]
  arc[start angle=-\startAngle,delta angle=2*\startAngle,radius=\lensRadius]
   -- cycle; % to get a better line end
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is/does the `delta angle` option do?

Comment: @dustin It is the difference between the start and the end angle. So it creates an arc that spans `delta angle` degrees.

Comment: Is the lack of the closing `)` in `asin(…` on purpose?

Comment: @HenriMenke No, that is what you'd call a mistake. Thanks. Still worked though ...

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[line join=round,fill=blue!15] (0,0) arc (-30:30:2 and 3) arc (150:210:2 and 3) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

From my previous TiKz studying:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=orange]
  ([shift={(-40:1cm)}]0,0) arc (-40:40:1cm);
   \draw[fill=orange,rotate=180]
  ([shift={(-40:1cm)}]-1.535,0) arc (-40:40:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just draw two lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue!15] (0,2) to[in=130,out=230] (0,-2) to[in=-50,out=50] (0,2) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]