# Recreating diffraction image with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I'd like to recreate the image below of an electron beam passing through -- and being diffracted by -- a carbon target onto a curved screen using TikZ.  Unfortunately it looks a bit beyond my skill level.  How could I recreate this?

[image]

Comment: Go to http://texdoc.net and search for pst-optic.  Look at the manual first then look at the examples.  These are being done with pstricks.  Also for tikz http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33460/tikz-library-for-optics To construct convex lenshttp://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180704/tikz-how-to-make-a-convex-lens

Comment: Next to the [`pst-optic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-optic) package, you may like to check out the [`pst-optexp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-optexp) package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an attempt from the procrastination team in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).  It actually turned out to be quite an nice diagram to draw; you just need to specify `ell` and `theta` and the radius of the screen as a proportion of `ell` and the program calculates the other angle required, using a combination of `sind`, `angle` and the Pythagorean subtraction operator `+-+`.

I was not sure how to represent what appear to be diffraction patterns on the OP screen, so I left them out.  The pink lines are just to show the construction and should be removed from a final version.  Enjoy!

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
% parameters
theta = 5;
ell = 10cm;
R   = 0.42 ell;

% calculate alpha
h = (ell-R)*sind(2theta);
alpha = 2theta + angle (R+-+h,h);

% define paths
path target, screen, a[];
target = unitsquare shifted -(.5,.5) xscaled 3 yscaled 12 shifted (R-ell,0);
screen = (R,0) rotated -1.1 alpha .. (R,0){up} .. (R,0) rotated 1.1 alpha;

% draw the various guides
drawoptions(withcolor .7 white);
draw (R-ell-1cm,0) -- (R+1cm,0) dashed dashpattern(on 40 off 6 on 8 off 6);
draw (R-ell,0) -- (R-ell,-2.5cm);
draw (R    ,0) -- (R    ,-2.5cm);
a1 = (R-ell,-2.2cm) -- (R, -2.2cm);
picture t; t = thelabel(btex $\ell$ etex,point 1/2 of a1);
drawdblarrow a1; unfill bbox t; draw t;

% draw the gubbins around the carbon target
drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 2);
draw (4 left -- right) scaled 4 shifted center target shifted 10 up;
draw (4 left -- right) scaled 4 shifted center target shifted 10 down;
drawoptions();
draw (up--down) scaled 10 shifted center target;
fill target; 

% and the screen
draw screen withpen pencircle scaled 2;
draw screen withpen pencircle scaled 1.2 withcolor background;

% add some beam arrows
drawarrow (20 left -- origin) shifted point 3.5 of target;
drawarrow center target -- (R-1,0) rotated alpha;
drawarrow center target -- (R-1,0) rotated -alpha;

% mark the beam angle
a2 = ((R,0) {up} .. (R,0) rotated(2 theta)) shifted (R-ell,0);
ahlength := 3; ahangle := 30;
drawdblarrow a2 withcolor .7 white;
label.rt(btex $2\theta$ etex, point .5 of a2) withcolor .7 white;

% add labels
label(btex Screen etex, point 1.6 of screen + 20 right);
label(btex Carbon target etex, center target + 24 up);

% this bit is just to show the construction, and should be deleted...
drawoptions(withcolor .7[red,white]);
fill fullcircle scaled 3;
draw subpath(-1,1) of fullcircle scaled 2R;
draw origin -- (R,0) rotated alpha; 
label(btex $\alpha$ etex, 25 right rotated 1/2 alpha);
%---------------------------------------------------------

endfig;
end.
```