# A way to draw a lab apparatus

Tags: graphics

Are there any packages that would make a simple lab apparatus easy to draw?

e.g. a spectrometer connected to a computer and has a wire before a light emitting tube, the wire also being connected to said spectrometer.

Comment: Maybe you need some GUI software, like xfig, Inkscape, MS Visio, EDraw, etc.

Comment: Dia (http://live.gnome.org/Dia) (similar to Visio but freeware) has lab equipment templates. And it can export pgf code.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The following are PSTricks packages for drawing lab apparatus:

- [pst-labo](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-labo) to draw lab apparatus related to chemistry.

  [image]
- [pst-pulley](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-pulley) to draw pulley.

  [image]
- [Various Physics diagrams and laboratory equipments](http://pstricks.blogspot.com/) that have not been bundled into packages. The site was very very cool! Unfortunately, its contents are written in French so we might have difficulties to understand even with the Google translator.

  **Particle Deflector:**

  [image]

  **Gear:**

  [image]