# How to create a "delay expansion" environment?

Tags: macros, environments, expansion, fp

I don't want to use the following

```
\begingroup
\edef\next{\endgroup
    \noexpand\const{Xp}{\X(tp)}
    \noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
    \noexpand\const{Xf}{\X(tf)}
    \noexpand\const{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
}\next
```

and

```
\begingroup
\edef\next{\endgroup
\noexpand\psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}}\next
```

because they seem to be cryptic.

Instead I want to create a new environment as follows,

```
\newenvironment{DelayExpansion}
{\begingroup
\edef\next\bgroup\endgroup\ignorespaces}
{\egroup\next\ignorespacesafterend}
```

but unfortunately it produces compilation errors that you can see by yourself.

If the errors can be fixed, the environment will be used as follows,

```
\DelayExpansion
  \noexpand\const{Xp}{\X(tp)}
  \noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
  \noexpand\const{Xf}{\X(tf)}
  \noexpand\const{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
\endDelayExpansion
```

and

```
\DelayExpansion
    \noexpand\psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}}
\endDelayExpansion
```

Or without specifying the `\noexpand` as follows.

```
\DelayExpansion
  \const{Xp}{\X(tp)}
  \const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
  \const{Xf}{\X(tf)}
  \const{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
\endDelayExpansion
```

and

```
\DelayExpansion
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}}
\endDelayExpansion
```

The MWE for the real scenario is given as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0,griddots=0,subgriddiv=5,gridwidth=0.4pt,subgridwidth=0.2pt}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\const{Vox}{2}
\const{Xo}{1}

\const{Voy}{4}
\const{Yo}{10}

\const{g}{10}

\def\X(#1){Xo+Vox*#1}
\def\Y(#1){Yo+Voy*#1-0.5*g*#1^2}

\const{tp}{Voy/g}
\const{toffset}{0.5}
\const{tf}{2*tp+toffset}

%\newenvironment{DelayExpansion}
%{\begingroup
%\edef\next\bgroup\endgroup\ignorespaces}
%{\egroup\next\ignorespacesafterend}
%
%\DelayExpansion
  %\noexpand\const{Xp}{\X(tp)}
    %\noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
    %\noexpand\const{Xf}{\X(tf)}
    %\noexpand\const{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
%\endDelayExpansion

\begingroup
\edef\next{\endgroup
    \noexpand\const{Xp}{\X(tp)}
    \noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
    \noexpand\const{Xf}{\X(tf)}
    \noexpand\const{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
}\next

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,\Yp)(\Xf,\Yf)
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,fillcolor=gray](0,\Yf)(\Xo,\Yo)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How to create a "delay expansion" environment?

### The latest update:

I have tried the solution given by Ryan, but it still produces some errors (please try it by yourself to see the error messages).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% cannot be simplified unless I must break my real scenario

\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\const{Xo}{1}
\const{Yo}{10}
\const{tp}{0.4}
\const{tf}{2*tp+1.5}

\def\X(#1){Xo+2*#1}
\def\Y(#1){Yo+4*#1-0.5*5*#1^2}


% try this for comparison first
%\begingroup
%\edef\next{\endgroup
    %\noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
%}\next

% Ryan's suggestin
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{DelayExpansion}{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\next{\endgroup\BODY}%
  \next%
}

% Ryan's suggestion
\begin{DelayExpansion}
    \noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
\end{DelayExpansion}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,6)(6,\Yp)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> I will offer 4 bounties of 500 each to a single accepted answer. Does it sound excited?

Comment: It sounds excitable, particularly given your deficit of 500 points to offer the fourth... :)

Comment: @RyanReich: Getting 500 in a week is possible. Don't worry. :D

Comment: Now that you've accepted my answer, I'm going to refuse three of your four bounties.  Although I put some effort into my answer I've written better, and other people put as much into their answers, and in all it's just wrong to single this one out and say "none of the others even compare!"  If it's worth so much to you one bounty at the maximum rate is enough.

Comment: @RyanReich: I am sorry. I have to do what I mentioned above. You devotes to get the 4 bounties of 500 each. An extra bounty of 500 will be given to David because of his "out-of-topic" idea but I use it in my production. :-)

Comment: Then, I find that your answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/a-way-to-draw-a-lab-apparatus/55944#55944 is exemplary and deserving of 1500 reputation worth of bounties :)

Comment: @RyanReich: Oh, it does not make any sense. :-) It is just an advertisement for PSTricks. No need educational effort to do "copy & paste" the links and figures. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This kind of thing is what the `environ` package exists for.  Try:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{DelayExpansion}{%
  \global\let\xBODY\BODY
}[\aftergroup\expandBODY]

\def\expandBODY{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\next{\endgroup\xBODY}%
  \next
}
```

It collects the entire environment before applying the `\edef` to it.

The reason your attempt failed is that `\edef` (and `\def`, and `\xdef`) require not just implicit braces such as `\bgroup` to set off their contents, but actual braces `{`.  It is not easy to split a `\def` across several macros for this reason, which is *exactly* why `environ` exists to collect the contents of an environment contained between two "start" and "end" macros.

I should also say that it's unlikely that you'll be able to write a version of this environment that works without `\noexpand` being explicitly specified at the desired places.  If you only want to `\noexpand` the beginning of the lines you can try to make `^^M` active before the environment and have it insert `\noexpand` itself, but that sounds very risky...

**Edit:** The cause of your errors is that your macro `\const` is internally making definitions via `\def`, yet the `environ` package runs its code *inside* the environment, where it is protected by a group (by design of environments).  Normally you'd just use `\gdef` or `\xdef` to circumvent this, but since to do that is to acquiesce to the peculiarities of one's coding environment a more automatic approach is to simply export the `\edef` outside the group using `\aftergroup`.  I've declared this export in two stages.  First, I export `\BODY` itself via `\global\let\BODY\BODY` and then, using the optional argument to `\NewEnviron` (which runs its contents at `\end{DelayExpansion}`), I export the expansion code.

This doesn't require any trickery (other than `\aftergroup`, which is pretty tricky) and also doesn't require hacking into the specific code of `\end` (as in `\end{DelayExpansion}`, except for knowing that there's a group in it.

**Edit 2:** Here is a slightly more complex environment that, in imitation of egreg's answer, can automatically preserve specified macros.  I'll give an example in a minimal case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}

\NewEnviron{DelayExpansion}[1][]{%
  \global\let\xBODY\BODY
  \global\def\xARGS{{#1}}
}[\aftergroup\expandBODY]

\def\expandBODY{%
  \begingroup
  \def\do##1{\let##1\relax}%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\xARGS
  \edef\next{\endgroup\xBODY}%
  \next
}

\begin{document}

\begin{DelayExpansion}[\macro]
  \def\macro{a}
\end{DelayExpansion}
\macro

\end{document}
```

(output: `a`)

Or, in your example,

```
\begin{DelayExpansion}[\const]
    \const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
\end{DelayExpansion}
```

Any macro named in the optional argument is not expanded (the list is comma-separated and may be empty, in which case the environment does nothing).

It doesn't use LaTeX3 but instead `etoolbox`, which provides some of the same programming conveniences for LaTeX2e.

Comment: @RyanReich Mixing global and local assignments to the same variable can be dangerous; at each call of the environment you're retaining `\BODY`; I'd use a different name: `\global\let\xBODY\BODY` and `\expandBODY` can use `\xBODY`.

Comment: @egreg: good point, fixed.

Comment: Could you please apply your latest edit to my real scenario such that I can compare it with Joseph's and Egreg's answer. The example in your latest edit seems to be sophisticated, but how to apply to my  real scenario?

Comment: Done.  It is mostly the same as my minimal example since only one macro is held back, but in general you can name more than one.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't use an environment, which has the problem of doing its work in a group. Here's a proposal:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DelayExpansion}{mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \cs_set_eq:NN ##1 \scan_stop: }
  \use:x { \group_end: #2 } 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\const{Vox}{2}
\const{Xo}{1}

\const{Voy}{4}
\const{Yo}{10}

\const{g}{10}

\def\X(#1){Xo+Vox*#1}
\def\Y(#1){Yo+Voy*#1-0.5*g*#1^2}

\const{tp}{Voy/g}
\const{toffset}{0.5}
\const{tf}{2*tp+toffset}

\begin{document}
\DelayExpansion{\const}
 {
  \const{Xp}{\X(tp)}
  \const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
  \const{Xf}{\X(tf)}
  \const{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
 }

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,\Yp)(\Xf,\Yf)
  \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tp}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\DelayExpansion` has two arguments; the first is a list of macros that shouldn't be expanded, the second argument is what will be expanded, except for the macros in the list.

[image]

In the example you have to use twice `\DelayExpansion`, because the macros `\Yp`, `\Xf` and `\Yf` wouldn't be available until they have been defined (by the first `\DelayExpansion`).

How does `\DelayExpansion` work?

First of all it makes (in a group) all chosen macros equivalent to `\relax` (which is `\scan_stop:` in LaTeX3 parlance). Then the second argument is given as argument to `\use:x` that fully expands everything (but `\scan_stop:` is not expandable, so in the first one `\const` will remain itself).

This is just a wrapper around the well known trick

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup<tokens>}\x
```

which is used also by Ryan. The `\group_end:` will make `\const` (or whatever macro is in the first argument) return to its previous value and LaTeX will continue its normal operations.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents Why? Of course this is only to show the potential; the `\begin{pspicture}` instruction can go outside the `\DelayExpansion` macro. But I'll edit. I believe that it's better to announce what shouldn't be expanded, rather than placing `\noexpand` manually: you don't risk to forget some.

Comment: +1 for getting the automatic `\noexpand`s

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Ryan's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102924/73), the definitions can be moved out of the group with a bit of expansion trickery:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% cannot be simplified unless I must break my real scenario

\newcommand{\const}[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\const{Xo}{1}
\const{Yo}{10}
\const{tp}{0.4}
\const{tf}{2*tp+1.5}

\def\X(#1){Xo+2*#1}
\def\Y(#1){Yo+4*#1-0.5*5*#1^2}


\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{DelayExpansion}{%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\begingroup
  \expandafter\edef\expandafter\next\expandafter
    {\expandafter\endgroup\BODY}%
  \next
  \begingroup
    \def\@currenvir{DelayExpansion}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{DelayExpansion}
    \noexpand\const{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
\end{DelayExpansion}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,6)(6,\Yp)
    \begin{DelayExpansion}
        \noexpand\psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
    \end{DelayExpansion}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 So far, it is the best candidate for the bounty. Thank you very much! It will be better (but not necessary) if you can implicitly add `\noexpand` behind the scene to free users from specifying it explicitly.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents You'll have to say how, exactly, you want that `\noexpand` added.  At the beginning of each line?  Automatically to specific macros?  Because it is impossible, in general, to read the author's mind as to which macros should be held back.

Comment: @RyanReich: It should prefix each macro defined inside the `DelayExpansion` with `\noexpand` automatically.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: So how would it know to catch `\const` but not `\X` or `\Y`?

Comment: @RyanReich: `\psparametricplot` apparently does not need delayed expansion. See my update please.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents The fact that one has to arrive at the desired list of macros to preserve by understanding the needs of each one individually suggests that you really want the facility provided by egreg or myself: just provide a list of macro names as arguments.  And again, I ask: how do I distinguish `\const` from `\X` or `\Y`?

Comment: @RyanReich: `\const` is the only macro that needs a delayed expansion whenever `\X(<another macro defined from \const>)` or `\Y(<another macro defined from \const>)` passed to it.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I mean for *general-purpose* use, not for this one motivational example, it would be necessary to individually analyze and specify the macros to preserve.  So I don't think it's a good idea to try to intuit what the author would want, because your use may change once you know this particular construction is available.

Comment: @RyanReich: I have no idea because I don't understand the internal details of my problems. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since there are several environment forms posted I think I'll ignore the suggested solution of an environment and offer an alternative. Using an environment for this seems inherently fragile and not at all LaTeX-like.

Just define an `\econst` variant of your `\const` macro that expands its second argument. (Such variants are the basis of the whole LaTeX3 xparse stack, but I'll use classic TeX syntax here).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0,griddots=0,subgriddiv=5,gridwidth=0.4pt,subgridwidth=0.2pt}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}
\def\econst#1#2{\edef\next##1{\noexpand\const{##1}{#2}}\next{#1}}


\const{Vox}{2}
\const{Xo}{1}

\const{Voy}{4}
\const{Yo}{10}

\const{g}{10}

\def\X(#1){Xo+Vox*#1}
\def\Y(#1){Yo+Voy*#1-0.5*g*#1^2}

\const{tp}{Voy/g}
\const{toffset}{0.5}
\const{tf}{2*tp+toffset}





\econst{Xp}{\X(tp)}
\econst{Yp}{\Y(tp)}
\econst{Xf}{\X(tf)}
\econst{Yf}{\Y(tf)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,\Yp)(\Xf,\Yf)
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,fillcolor=gray](0,\Yf)(\Xo,\Yo)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{0}{\tf}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Or if you don't need the unexpanded form and want the expanded form to have an optional argument you could directly define `\econst` rather than make it a variant of `\const`.

```
\newcommand\econst[3][3]{%
    \edef\next{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\next:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}
```

Comment: +1 You deserve to get my another extra bounty of 500 for this idea and effort.

Comment: As I can also invoke `\econst{g}{10}` (for example) in spite of `\const{g}{10}`, then it will be better to make `\const` private with different name and changing `\econst` to `\const`. Thus we have only a multi-purpose `\const` at the end. What do you think?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I wondered about that but didn't know if you needed the unexpanded form in other contexts, also the way I did econst hid your optional argument with default 3 if you made `\const` internal you might want econst to have an optional argument too? (which is easy enough to do)

Comment: I need the optional argument for the final `\const` (based on my explanation above). Do  you have time to make it? :D

Comment: Is it correct `\newcommand{\const}[3][3]{\edef\next##1{\noexpand\temporary[#1]{##1}{#3}}\next{#2}}`? where `\newcommand\temporary[3][3]{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\endcsname{round(#3:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}`?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents looks OK or see version in updated question

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use it for my production. The first 4 bounties of 500 each will be given for the accepted answer (on the topic, it has not been decided yet) and you will only get the fifth bounty of 500.

Comment: You really don't have to bankrupt yourself:-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of Ryan's solution without *etoolbox* package. `\dolist` could have been replaced by LaTeX's `\@for`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\begingroup
\catcode`\,=\active
\gdef\dolist#1#2{%
  \begingroup\toks0{}%
  \def,##1{\toks0\expandafter{\the\toks0 #2}}%
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \scantokens{,#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\the\toks0 %
}
\endgroup

\NewEnviron{DelayExpansion}[1][]{%
  \global\let\xBODY\BODY
  \gdef\xARGS{#1}%
}[\aftergroup\expandBODY]

\def\expandBODY{%
  \begingroup
  \ifx\xARGS\empty\else
    \expandafter\dolist\expandafter{\xARGS}{\let##1\relax}%
  \fi
  \edef\next{\endgroup\xBODY}\next
}

\begin{document}
\def\xmacro{a}
\begin{DelayExpansion}[\macro,\foo]
  \def\foo##1{##1}%
  \def\macro{\xmacro}
  x
\end{DelayExpansion}
\macro
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show me how to apply your answer to my real scenario given above?

Comment: Please use my solution the same way you would Ryan’s solution. All I have done is to avoid the need to load *etoolbox* package. If you needed *etoolbox* for other purposes, then my solution is only of theoretical interest.