# How can I draw these pictures in LaTeX (with TikZ)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I want to draw these pictures with **TikZ**. But I can not.
Please guide me in this regard.
[image]

Comment: Please post some code showing your efforts so far. Then others can help with the parts that are causing problems.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/a-way-to-draw-a-lab-apparatus

Comment: Also, please choose more informative titles for your questions. At the moment, you have "How to draw this pictures with TikZ?" and
"How can I draw these pictures in LaTeX (with TikZ)?", which sounds like it's the same question.

Comment: Do you really need to draw with tikZ these images? You could just add this image on a Latex text...
I have some experience with tikZ, and that would take you a lot of time if you dont have a lot of experience...! I let you a manual of tikZ thats explains you all about tikZ from the basis... But you will see that what you are asking for its quite complicate...
[Tikz Manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) Buena Suerte!

Comment: You may try my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145913) to [How to create the following figures in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145883).

Comment: Please add a MWE and someone (expert user, I think) can help you!

Comment: Why a `-2` as downvote? I thought it was agreed that a `-1` would suffice to indicate to the OP that her/his question needs improvement and that is why there are comments.

Comment: @azetina Look at the total vote count ;-)

Comment: For the illustrations like this I'd suggest to use Inkscape with snapping and axonometric grid both enabled (Ctrl+Shift+D -> Grids -> Creation).

Answer (score 11):

A modified version of something I did the other day just as a start:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    pics/profdiwb/.style n args={2}{
      code={
        \path [draw, line cap=round, #1, pic actions] (0,0) arc (180:0:#2/15) coordinate (tiwb1) -- +(0,-#2) coordinate (tiwb2) arc (-180:0:#2/6) coordinate (tiwb3) -- + (0,#2) coordinate (tiwb4) arc (180:0:#2/15);
        \coordinate (tiwb5) at ($(tiwb1)!1/3!(tiwb2)$);
        \coordinate (tiwb12) at ($(tiwb3)!2/3!(tiwb4)$);
        \begin{scope}[fill=#1!50, draw=#1]
            \clip (tiwb1) -- (tiwb2) arc (-180:0:#2/6) -- (tiwb4);
            \path [fill=#1!50, draw=#1, decoration={snake, amplitude=#2/50}, segment length=#2/5, decorate, pic actions] ($(tiwb2) - (#2/5,#2/5)$) -| ($(tiwb12) + (#2/5,0)$) -- ($(tiwb5) - (#2/5,0)$) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
        \path [draw, line cap=round, #1, pic actions] (0,0) arc (180:0:#2/15) coordinate (tiwb1) -- +(0,-#2) coordinate (tiwb2) arc (-180:0:#2/6) coordinate (tiwb3) -- + (0,#2) coordinate (tiwb4) arc (180:0:#2/15);
        \path [fill=white, draw=#1, line width=.0075*#2]
          ($(tiwb1)!3/4!(tiwb3)$) coordinate (tiwb7) circle (.0275*#2)
          ($(tiwb7)!1/3!(tiwb2)$) coordinate (tiwb8) circle (.02*#2)
          ($(tiwb4)!5/7!(tiwb2)$) coordinate (tiwb11) circle (.025*#2)
          ($(tiwb1)!5/6!(tiwb7)$) circle (.03*#2)
          ($(tiwb2)!1/2!(tiwb4)$) coordinate (tiwb6) circle (.035*#2)
          ($(tiwb2)!1/2!(tiwb3) + (.025*#2,0)$) coordinate (tiwb9) circle (.015*#2)
          ($(tiwb9)!1/2!(tiwb8) - (.025*#2,0)$) circle (.0175*#2)
          ($(tiwb9) - (.01*#2,.075*#2)$) circle (.01*#2)
          ($(tiwb1)!1/3!(tiwb3)$) coordinate (tiwb10) circle (.04*#2)
          ($(tiwb1)!1/2!(tiwb4)!1/3!(tiwb6)$) circle (.05*#2)
          ($(tiwb1)!1/2!(tiwb4)!1/7!(tiwb10)$) circle (.035*#2)
          ($(tiwb1)!1/2!(tiwb4)!0.001!(tiwb11) + (.05*#2,.05*#2)$) circle (.02*#2)
          ;
        \draw [black, thin, <->] ($(tiwb3) + (2.5pt,0)$) -- ($(tiwb5 -| tiwb4) + (2.5pt,0)$);
      }
    },
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw pic {profdiwb={magenta}{20pt}};
    \draw pic at (15pt,0) {profdiwb={red}{20pt}};
    \draw pic at (30pt,0) {profdiwb={orange}{20pt}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Test-Tubes]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use this code but figure does not appear. I show errors: line 35: Use of \tikz@parabola doesn't match its definition. \draw pi
line 36: Use of \tikz@parabola doesn't match its definition. \draw pi
line 37: Use of \tikz@parabola doesn't match its definition. \draw pi
line 38: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
line 38: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
line 38: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 38: Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 38: Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
line 38: Missing \endgroup

Comment: @AlirezaAlipour You need TikZ v3.00

Comment: As @percusse says, you need TikZ 3 for this in order to get the support for `pics`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to draw this pictures with pspicture. I include some packages, for example: \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}, \usepackage{pstricks-add}, \usepackage{pdftricks}, \usepackage{pst-labo}. Addition, I include some file in my folder that included main.tex. This files are: pst-labo.sty, pst-labo.tex, pst-laboObj.tex and xkeyval.dtx.

MY TeX Live version is 2014 and compile with Xelatex. but figure does not appear.

Comment: @AlirezaAlipour You said you wanted to use TikZ in the question! In any case, I don't understand the point of your comment: those packages have nothing to do with TikZ. You need to update to TikZ 3 to use this code. Of course, you could draw the picture with `pspicture` (I assume) but that would have nothing to do with any version of TikZ. These are different packages for producing diagrams: `pstricks` etc.; `pgf`/`tikz`; `metapost`; and so on. They each work differently in terms of environments, commands and so on, and you cannot expect the commands for one to do anything for the others.

Comment: @AlirezaAlipour If you are using TeX Live 2014, you should have TikZ 3, at least if your installation is up to date. Please update and then run my code again exactly as it is. Also, you shouldn't need to add those files in your working directory even if you are using `pstricks` as they are part of the standard distribution, and `.dtx` is not something you can use directly without processing it to produce the relevant `.sty` and/or `.tex` files in any case.