# income distribution champagne glass in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to draw [this](http://www.google.gr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/2001/12/images/wade-c1.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/2001/12/wade.htm&h=356&w=375&sz=14&tbnid=RKYD36bvmc55WM%3a&tbnh=101&tbnw=106&zoom=1&usg=__5M2dK1qhZ4P4kDZmjwi0v0BvlpY=&docid=bHHIEgn0Uqn-PM&sa=X&ei=rteVUse6DI_H7AbhgYGIAw&ved=0CDIQ9QEwAQ) or [this](http://www.franciscansisters.org/english/jpic/images/champagne.gif). However, it is really hard for me to create the concave part of these images and seperate the picture into 5 equal parts.

Comment: Please add code of your attempts until now and show us, where exactly your are getting problems. Like this, it is just a "do it for me" question. Thank you.

Comment: –1: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Notify me, when you added some more information an I’d be happy to redeem my downvote …

Comment: I think this is one of the examples where the quicker route might be to generate the graph in [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and use (a `LaTeX`) export in your document instead of generating the plot in `LaTeX`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Drawing with Bézier curves can take a bit of getting used to, and may involve some trial and error when trying to code curves in `tikz` rather than drawing them using a vector graphics program.

The following shows how I got what appears to be the required shape. The `show curve controls` decoration is only there to illustrate the control points I used.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
  show curve controls/.style={
    decoration={
      show path construction,
        curveto code={
          \draw [gray, thick] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
            .. controls (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) .. (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
          \draw [red, thick] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta);
          \draw [red, thick] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
          \fill [black] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) circle [radius=2pt]
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast)  circle [radius=2pt];
          \fill [blue] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) circle [radius=2pt]
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)  circle [radius=2pt];
        }
      },
   decorate}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-5,0) grid (5,10);
\path  [fill=gray!20, fill opacity=0.5, postaction=show curve controls]
    (-5,10) 
    .. controls ++(270:2) and ++(100:4) .. (-1/2,6)
    .. controls ++(280:1) and ++(90:2)  .. (-1/4,0)
    -- (1/4,0)
    .. controls ++(90:2) and ++(260:1) .. (1/2, 6)
    .. controls ++(80:4) and ++(270:2) .. (5,10) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use some [LaTeX/PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55944/41529) packages [for chemists](http://web.archive.orgj/web/20111125023145/http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~collas/Latex/LaTeX-CIES-SlideShow.pdf) as explained by Denis Girou and retransmitted by
Benjamin Collas. They may be [difficult to integrate in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4563/41529). Here is an example from page 50 (25 of PDF):

```
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\pstChauffageBallon[glassType=flacon,recuperationGaz,
tubeRecourbeCourt,substance={\pstFilaments[10]{gray}}]
```

[image: example of package pst-labo by Denis Girou and Benjamin Collas]

You may also use pst-plot, or pst-text, see page 49 of same link.

Comment: Very nice, but I don't think this answers the OP's question. If you take a look at the two links in the question, you'll see that the OP is after a particular curve that sort of looks like a champagne glass, not after a way of drawing actual glasses.